# Ng Bootstrap rating star color based on selected count

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I‘m implementig a star rating with a custom rating template. I want to change the color of the selected stars based on the count that is currently selected. E.g 4 selected stars = green, 3 selected stars = orange, ...

I saw in the documentation of ng-bootstrap that the StarTemplateContext interface has two properties `fill` and `index`. Based on this properties I was able to change the color on a specific index. E.g first star green, second star orange.

```html
 <ngb-rating [starTemplate]="t" [rate]=data.stars></ngb-rating>
```

```html
<ng-template #t let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
  <span class="star" [class.full]="fill === 100" [class.green]="index === 4" [class.orange]="index === 3">
    <i class="fas fa-square square-star"></i>
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

But now I want to have all the selected stars in the same color. Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: just put the .filled css in last place and remove all .filled.class, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfevz9?file=app/rating-template.ts

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. See my solution below.

Comment: ::glups:: Really I'd misunderstood your question, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to add the `ng-template` into the `ngb-rating` tag where the rate value is known.

```html
<div *ngFor="let rating of data">
<ngb-rating [rate]="rating" [max]=4>
  <ng-template let-fill="fill">
    <span class="star color{{rating}}" [class.filled]="fill === 100">&#9733;</span>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-rating>
</div>
```

See the running solution here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfevz9-jpxukv